# Laravel: ¿cómo modificar la tabla notifications e introducir datos distintos a los que se insertan por defecto?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-7, laravel-8

Estoy implementando el sistema de notificaciones de Laravel. He hecho una prueba de inserción en DB y ha salido bien pero al registrar la notificación veo que esta llega con datos "raros" (desde mi punto de vista).

| id | type | notifiable_type | notifiable_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 634db0ee-a9c0... | App\Notifications\HeatMapNotification | App\Models\User | 1 |

La columna "id" no entiendo por qué viene un id con tipo uuid. Es decir, con un id autoincremental sería suficiente (creo).

En la columna "type" me gustaría insertar un texto mucho más sencillo.

A la columna "notifiable_type" no le veo ningún uso. En mi caso las entidades notificables siempre van a ser usuarios.

Además me gustaría cambiar algunos nombres de columnas.

¿Cómo podría hacer estos cambios?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Con una [migración](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#modifying-columns) probaste? Sólo ten en cuenta que esas columnas son para que funcionen como una relación polimórfica, y cambiarlas implica que no podrás usar el sistema de notificaciones que trae laravel y tendrás que hacer el tuyo personalizado

Comment: Sí, he probado así pero echa en falta algunos de los campos con lo que viene de base.